# Android - GridView with two actions per item

Tags: android, gridview

I believe this is a very common task:
A GridView is inflated with custom layouts as items. Every layout consists of an image and a button. If user clicks on an image, one action is performed (e.g. the image is shown).
If user presses a button - another action (deletion of the item from the GridView).
The former is implemented inside onItemClick() of AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.
How one implements the latter?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: The simplest way I can say is that set the position to your view's TAG and then in your onClick method get the TAG value and cast it to integer.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase the question

Comment: I don't think posting my code will help as it's exactly the same as in tutorials

Comment: @SaeidFarivar Thank you, it's worked. Please submit your comment as the answer so I'll be able to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I can say is that set the position to your view's TAG and then in your onClick method get the TAG value and cast it to integer. (per @sad1raf 's request I added my comment as an answer!)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom ArrayAdapter and put it to the GridView.
 Pass both the context and the Class you want to call after you have delete the object. The most important thing is to pass an array with data that will be used for filling all cells (in your case, an array of integers).
Then inside

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

you have to:

- Open database connection and get data
- Create a Dialog to make safer data delete
- Show dialog by pressing button

For the second step you could do something like that:

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    builder.setTitle("Warning");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to permanently delete the selected item?");
    builder.setCancelable(true);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
            dao.deleteEventData(item);
            MyUtility.startActivityNoAnimsClearTop(context, classToLaunch);
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

In my code I use DAO database connection, it's a good way to manage data, but instead of dao.deleteEventData(item) you could put every code you need for delete images. Then when you press the button you display the dialog.

```
    Button btnDeleteList = (Button)cell.findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteList);
    btnDeleteList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            builder.show();
        }
    });
```